# SelectedValue in ComboBox always returns 0

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, enums

I am using the Enum class to allow myself to Convert from Enum to Description easily. I know there are other ways to do this, but this is how my company has done it in the past so I need to stick to the same structure.

Here is my enum class:

```
 [TypeConverter(typeof(EnumToStringUsingDescription))]    
    public enum ArTypes
    {
        [Description("Adjustment")]
        [EnumInformation("Adjustment", true, 1)]
        arAdjustment = 1,
        [Description("Payment")]
        [EnumInformation("Payment", true, 2)]
        arPayment = 3,
        [Description("Deposit Receipt")]
        [EnumInformation("Deposit Receipt", true, 3)]
        arDepositReceipt = 5,
        [Description("Deposit Applied")]
        [EnumInformation("Deposit Applied", true, 4)]
        arDepositApplied = 7,
        [Description("Bad Debt Transfer")]
        [EnumInformation("Bad Debt Transfer", true, 5)]
        arBadDebtTransfer = 9,
        [Description("Bad Debt Writeoff")]
        [EnumInformation("Bad Debt Writeoff", true, 6)]
        arBadDebtWriteoff = 11,
        [Description("Bad Debt Recovery")]
        [EnumInformation("Bad Debt Recovery", true, 7)]
        arBadDebtRecovery = 13,
        [Description("Charge")]
        [EnumInformation("Charge", true, 8)]
        arCharge = 15,
        [Description("Immediate Case Receipt")]
        [EnumInformation("Immediate Cash Receipt", true, 9)]
        arImmediateCashReceipt = 17,
        [Description("Over Payment")]
        [EnumInformation("Over Payment", true, 10)]
        arOverPayment = 19,
        [Description("Balance Forward")]
        [EnumInformation("Balance Forward", true, 11)]
        arBalanceForward = 21,
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="ArType: " Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ArTypeList}"
                             DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                             SelectedValuePath="Value"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="190"
                             SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedArType, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                             TabIndex="5"  Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"
                             Style="{StaticResource RadComboBoxStyle}" />
```

TotalAdjustmentsOptionsViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<String, ArTypes>> _ArTypeList;
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<String, ArTypes>> ArTypeList
{
    get
    {
        if (_ArTypeList == null)
        {

            _ArTypeList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, ArTypes>>();

            EnumToStringUsingDescription converter = new EnumToStringUsingDescription();
            ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, ArTypes>> dateTypeList = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, ArTypes>>();

            foreach (ArTypes type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ArTypes)))
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, ArTypes> typeKeyValue = new KeyValuePair<string, ArTypes>(converter.ConvertTo(null, null, type, typeof(string)).ToString(), type);
                _ArTypeList.Add(typeKeyValue);
            }
        }

        return _ArTypeList;
    }
    set
    {
        _ArTypeList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ArTypeList");
    }
}



 private ArTypes _SelectedArType;
        public ArTypes SelectedArType
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedArType;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_SelectedArType != value)
                {
                    _SelectedArType = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedArType");
                }
            }
        }
```

TotalAdjustmentsWidget(View):

```
private ArTypes _SelectedArType;
    public ArTypes SelectedArType
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedArType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedArType != value)
            {
                _SelectedArType = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

TotalAdjustmentsWidgetViewModel:

```
   public ArTypes SelectedArType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.SettingModel.SelectedArType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.SettingModel.SelectedArType != value)
            {
                this.SettingModel.SelectedArType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedArType");
            }
        }
    }
//This List is what actually pulls the data for the created widget

        public List<CustomerActivityReport> GetAllCustomerTypeReportsData()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!CanLoad)
                    return null;


                List<CustomerActivityReport> customerTypeReports = dashRepo.GetCustomerActivityReport(1, Convert.ToInt32(SelectedArType), 3, 1, this.Dates.StartDate, 
                                                                                                          this.Dates.EndDate, BeginningRoute, EndingRoute, BeginningAccountNumber,
                                                                                                          EndingAccountNumber, BeginningSequenceNumber, EndingSequenceNumber,
                                                                                                          0, 1, printCustomerTypeTotals, SelectedServiceType.ServiceTypeID,
                                                                                                          SelectedRate.RateID, SelectedCycle.CycleID, -1, SelectedCustomerType.CustomerTypeID);

                return customerTypeReports;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogException(ex);
            }
            return null; 

        }
```

The ComboBox is populated with the right values, so that is working properly. The ArTypeList stores the values for example as: {"Adjustment", arAdjustment}
I have put breakpoints at all of the gets/sets in the TotaAdjustments ViewModels and View.
Result:

> The SelectedArType in the OptionsViewModel is initially set to 0.
>   Once I select an item from the combobox the selectedArType is then set to arDepositReceipt(or which ever one I have chosen)
>   I then click on the button that sends the information to my Widget.
>   Once I click the button the breakpoint goes to my SelectedArType in My TotalAdjustmentsWidgetViewModel.
>   The value of SelectedArType is 0 instead of arDepositReceipt
>   The breakpoint then goes to the SelecedArType in my Model and it is also set to 0.

This causes the value for SelectedArType to be 0 instead of arDepositReceipt.

I have 2 ViewModels for this Model. The TotalAdjustmentsOptionsViewModel is for the user to set the parameters for the actual widget. The TotalAdjustmentsViewModel is for the actual widget that displays the data that matches the given parameters.

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Right, I see a `SelectedArType` property in two view models... what is the value of that property in the `GetAllCustomerTypeReportsData` method? Is that the one that is called from the `Button.Click`?

Comment: Yes that method is called from the button click and it is set to 0 at that point as well.

Comment: Basically long story short, SelectedArType is being setin the OptionsViewModel, but not the other one.

Comment: So the actual `ComboBox` part in the `OptionsViewModel` is working fine? It sounds to me like you're correctly setting the property in one view model but then trying to use the property from another view model in your method. If that is correct, please edit your question adding the relationship between your two view models. Unfortunately, I'm about to disappear for a few hours soon, but I'll try to take a look when I return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm still struggling to fully understand your setup but I think I have an idea now. If this is not correct, please let me know... as far as I can understand, you have a `TotalAdjustmentsViewModel` (or `TotalAdjustmentsWidgetViewModel` depending on where in your question you look) class and a `TotalAdjustmentsOptionsViewModel` class.

I'm kind of hoping that the `TotalAdjustmentsOptionsViewModel` class is a child view model of the other one. If that is true, then you have a nice simple solution to your problem. You could `Bind` directly from the `TotalAdjustmentsOptionsView` control directly to the parent view model. (I'm also assuming that what you labelled as 'XAML' in your question is actually from the child view):

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ArTypeList}" SelectedValue="{Binding 
    Path=DataContext.SelectedArType, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=
    {x:Type YourViewsXmlNamespacePrefix:TotalAdjustmentsViewModel}}}" ... />
```

Please let me know if I have misunderstood the situation.